# SQL Server connection using Get-StoredCredential

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to update my script to use `Get-StoredCredential` for creating a connection to SQL-Server. Below is what I've tried so far without success:

```
$creds = Get-StoredCredential -Target dbStoredCredentials

$newConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$newConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=my-apps-server;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;"
$newConnection.Credential = $creds
```

This causes the following error:

```
Exception setting "Credential": "Cannot convert the "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" value of type
"System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" to type "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential"."
```

How can I get the SQL connection to authenticate with StoredCredential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential` means you're using SQL Server Authentication.  It's equivalent to putting the username and password in the connection string.

If you want to use a stored Windows credential, then create a Windows Credential targeting `YourSQLServer:port` (eg `myserver.mydomain.com:1433`) and use
`Integrated Security=true` in your connection string. The driver will access the credential store for you and perform NTLM authentication using the stored credential rather than the identity of the thread opening the connection.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to avoid using login credentials like this. Using integrated credentials was what i was hoping to use here.

Comment: Ok, changed the answer.

Comment: Will this assume the credentials for the user account logged in? I'm looking to use the credentials stored in Windows Credential Manager

Comment: Yes.  See eg https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3250/connect-to-sql-servers-in-another-domain-using-windows-authentication/